# Sorting an excel column with numbers and keep track of cell indices

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, database, spreadsheet

So, this is my problem, I have two excel columns like :

- 1 // 0.5
- 2  // 3.3
- 3  // 1.2

I would like to sort the second column in ascending(or descending)  order, and also change the first column as the second does:
The result i want is :

- 1 // 0.5
- 3  // 1.2
- 2  // 3.3

Is there a way ?

Comment: try first hit on google https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk00D9tV0JjE8W0HK-QmlELuBFP-lAw%3A1602661162143&source=hp&ei=KquGX8GmBvadjLsP-v2D-As&q=sort+data+excel&oq=sort+data+ex&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAxgAMgUIABDJAzICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjoHCCMQyQMQJzoECC4QJzoECCMQJzoECAAQQzoICAAQsQMQgwE6DgguELEDEIMBEMcBEKMCOgUIABCRAjoLCAAQsQMQgwEQkQI6BwgAELEDEEM6CwguELEDEMcBEKMCOg4ILhCxAxCDARDHARCvAToICC4QsQMQgwE6CwgAELEDEIMBEMkDOgUIABCxAzoFCC4QsQM6AgguOggIABCxAxDJAzoKCC4QxwEQowIQCjoECAAQClCJAli5GmDdIWgAcAB4AIABhQGIAfoIkgEDOC40mAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=psy-ab

Comment: Yes, thank you It was "sort by more than one column"

Comment: You can sort Column 2 directly... https://i.stack.imgur.com/nM6Fp.gif

Comment: First assign headers to both columns,,, (for better management) then select both,, go to SORT,,, hit CUSTOM Sort,,, select COLUMN 2 to Sort by and order lowest to highest !